# PHP MySQL Multi column query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in the DB

```
tbl1: Items

Items tbl      : id | item_name  | item_price | item_qty
Items tbl Row 1: 1  | laptop     | 100        | 10
Items tbl Row 2: 1  | television | 80         | 10
Items tbl Row 3: 1  | mobile     | 60         | 10

tbl2: Orders
Orders tbl     : id | order_num | items_id | items_prices | items+qty | amount
Orders tbl Row1: 1  | OR222879  | ["1,3"]  | ["100,60"]   | ["10,6"]  | 1360;
```

I can't make a query returns Order's Items Data I'm using Codeigniter.

Comment: Welcome! To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you.**

Comment: use MySQL FIND_IN_SET() method in where condition to check items_id in the column value.

Answer (score 0):

The more easier and effective solution would be to normalise your data and have each Item ID as separate rows in a different table.

Items - Orders - OrderItems

Orders - id | order_num | total 
OrderItems - id | order_num | item_id | quantity

Using this structure you can select all rows using the 'order_num' from the OrderItems table.